# Как сдвинуть fixed элементы вниз?

Tags: css, position

https://jsfiddle.net/o207fo2L/

Хочу сдвинуть меню и выезжающий блок на 30 пикселей вниз, то есть, чтобы кнопка была ниже и сам блок меню тоже. Пробовал менять параметр top, но почему-то он ни на что не влияет. Мне казалось, что в случае fixed элемент фиксируется на видимой области экрана и их можно двигать с помощью параметров top left.  Более того, если убрать параметр top произойдет сдвиг кнопки вообще в левую сторону. При этом если написать

```
 top: 15px;
 bottom:150px;
```

То сдвиг все-таки будет, правда, видимо, именно по нижней границе элемента. Почему так, кто может все это объяснить?

И еще, может лучше использовать margin-top для сдвига вниз, так как вверху будет шапка сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задается без проблем `.hidden-menu, .btn-menu { top: 30px; }`

```css
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*-----------------Код для левого меню-----------------*/
.hidden-menu {
  position: fixed;//Видимо чтобы не менять своего положения при прокрутке экрана
  list-style:none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  left: -220px;
  transition: left .2s;
 top: 30px;
}


.hidden-menu-ticker {
  display: none;
}

.btn-menu {
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;//Чтобы сделать label блочным элементом, после чего можно применить к нему width
  top: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left .23s;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  
  top: 30px;
}
.btn-menu span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  transition: all .1s linear .23s;
}
.btn-menu span.first {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {
  left: 180px;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {
  left: 0;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 8px;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -8px;
}
/*-----------------Конец кода для левого меню-----------------*/
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
  <span class="third"></span>
</label>
<ul class="hidden-menu">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не могу понять, почему работает только если поменять местами top: 15px; left: 5px;? То есть если сразу поставить left то работать будет, но не наоборот.